# an API to speech some text that does't work with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I need  some help as I'm trying to use an API to speech a text. Some days ago I wrote a PHP class to   get that, but I had problems with the typical vowels of the German language like ä, ö, etc. or those of the Italian  like è, é, ò, à etc, which were not converted the right way, even though the charset was set in UTF-8. I tried so hard, but I had to give up. Then I sent an email to the API admins, who sent me back some info about the API itself, and also 2 files with a simple example of how to use it the right way.

Now I'd like to get something more: I mean, I'd like to add a function: I'd like to have a Select tag to  let my users choose a language, and then a textarea tag to let 'em write a word or a sentence in that language, of course, and finally a Speech button  so that they can hear the exact pronunciation of what they typed.

I'm stuck with the AJAX part, I think, that's the file I called  **'new-text.php'** which has this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function speechText() {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'speech-text.php',
            async: true,
            dataType: 'text',
            dataType: 'select',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: "text=" + $("#srcText").val(),
            success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) { console.log(data); $("#audioPlayer").attr("src", data); },

         data: { "select": $("#language option:selected").val() },

            error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(errorThrown); }
        });

        }
    </script>           

    <p>
        <select id="language" style="width: 200px">
            <option value="">------- Select language -------</option>
            <option value="ca-es">Catalan</option>
            <option value="zh-cn">Chinese (China)</option>
            <option value="zh-hk">Chinese (Hong Kong)</option>
            <option value="zh-tw">Chinese (Taiwan)</option>
            <option value="da-dk">Danish</option>
            <option value="nl-nl">Dutch</option>
            <option value="en-au">English (Australia)</option>
            <option value="en-ca">English (Canada)</option>
            <option value="en-gb">English (Great Britain)</option>
            <option value="en-in">English (India)</option>
            <option value="en-us">English (United States)</option>
            <option value="fi-fi">Finnish</option>
            <option value="fr-ca">French (Canada)</option>
            <option value="fr-fr">French (France)</option>
            <option value="de-de">German</option>
            <option value="it-it">Italian</option>
            <option value="ja-jp">Japanese</option>
            <option value="ko-kr">Korean</option>
            <option value="nb-no">Norwegian</option>
            <option value="pl-pl">Polish</option>
            <option value="pt-br">Portuguese (Brazil)</option>
            <option value="pt-pt">Portuguese (Portugal)</option>
            <option value="ru-ru">Russian</option>
            <option value="es-mx">Spanish (Mexico)</option>
            <option value="es-es">Spanish (Spain)</option>
            <option value="sv-se">Swedish (Sweden)</option>
        </select>
    </p>

        <textarea id="srcText" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Speech" onclick="speechText();"/>
            <audio id="audioPlayer" src="" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Then the second file which is used by this one here, called **'speech-text.php'**, which has the task of using the API thru the cURL library.
Here I guess all's ok. I can't see any error.

As I'm not very good at AJAX, I do think there's something wrong in the first file.

The other file, I called 'speech-text.php' has this code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

  // MY API-KEY: 611e0eb0f671415788150de40f609bdd

if ( isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['language']) )
    {
        $ch = curl_init("http://api.voicerss.org/?key=611e0eb0f671415788150de40f609bdd&c=mp3&f=48khz_16bit_stereo");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "src=" . $_POST['text'] .
                                             "hl="  . $_POST['language']);


        $audioStream = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        echo "data:audio/mp3;base64," . base64_encode($audioStream);
    }
?>
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: You cannot have 2 `datatype` as in `dataType: 'text', dataType: 'select',`

Comment: You have two `dataType` properties set in the Ajax function. Also, you might find that the special characters get mangled during the POST ~ perhaps try encoding the data using `json_encode` before sending and decoding in php before sending as data to the api

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to send 2 pieces of data to your PHP script from your javascript so

Change this line to include both items

```
data: "text=" + $("#srcText").val(),
```

To

```
date: {text: $("#srcText").val(), language: $("#language").val()},
```

Oh and of course like my comment suggested, also remove the `dataType: 'select',` line

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it doesn't work at all; I mean, if I write down something in German as: Österreich ist etwas geändert heute.  and I choose, of course, German from the Select, I can listen to something spelled in English!  That's the default language of the API, which is not able to retrieve the right value from the Select and then pass it to the written sentence. In fact, at the end of this sort of 'new language' that I get now, I can hear this value passed, that's **hl=de-de** which should not be spelled, but instead received from my 'speech-text.php' file mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

it seems when you choose language parameters it never change to API key url in it. Try set the value in JavaScript variable then use that variable in your API key settings url. Hopefully this will remove your language select problems. I have seen you never set the language parameters inside API URL. Hopefully you can follow the instructions above which others are mentioned also correct.